# Why using static results in a different output?

Tags: java

I have the following code that prints 20.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class A {
    public int val = 20; // <- no static
}


class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        updateVal(a);
        
        System.out.println(a.val);
    }
    
    private static void updateVal(A a) {
        a = new A();
        a.val = 50;
    }
}
```

But if I change val to static then it prints 50. How it works?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class A {
    public static int val = 20; // <- there is static
}


class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        updateVal(a);
        
        System.out.println(a.val);
    }
    
    private static void updateVal(A a) {
        a = new A();
        a.val = 50;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you do `a = new A();` then you are no longer dealing with the `A` you passed in. You are dealing with a new `A`. When you do `a.val = 50` then you are assigning the value of **the new A**. If the value is static then the new A and the old A point to the same static value. Which, an IDE will warn you, should be referenced as `A.val = 50;` to remove confusion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: In the static case, `a.val` is not really `a.val`, but `A.val` (all instances share the same field)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the field is non-static, each instance has its own `val` field with its own value. Since Java is pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference, the statement `a = new A()` inside `updateVal` does **not** update the `val` field of the instance that was created in `main.`

If the field is static, all instances share the same field. The update inside `updateVal` is now that one shared field.